# Gammu Cannot Start Service Due to SQL Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, odbc, sms-gateway, gammu

I have installed Gammu, and I use the 1.33 version

I got some error that I copied from logs.

> Tue 2015/04/14 11:00:28 gammu-smsd[7272]: SQL failure: 2
>   Tue 2015/04/14 11:00:28 gammu-smsd[7272]: Error inserting into database (SMSDSQL_InitAfterConnect)
>   Tue 2015/04/14 11:00:28 gammu-smsd[7272]: Post initialisation failed, stopping Gammu smsd: Unknown error. (UNKNOWN[27])
>   Tue 2015/04/14 11:00:28 gammu-smsd[7272]: Terminating communication...
>   Tue 2015/04/14 11:03:13 gammu-smsd[2816]: Using generic SQL for ODBC, this might fail. In such case please set SQL configuration option.
>   Tue 2015/04/14 11:03:13 gammu-smsd[2816]: Connected to Database odbc: aptikad on sms
>   Tue 2015/04/14 11:03:13 gammu-smsd[2816]: Created Windows RW shared memory at 0000000002D60000
>   Tue 2015/04/14 11:03:13 gammu-smsd[2816]: Starting phone communication...
>   Tue 2015/04/14 11:03:21 gammu-smsd[2816]: Inserting phone info
>   Tue 2015/04/14 11:03:21 gammu-smsd[2816]: SQLExecDirect failed, Code = -1, ODBC diagnostics:
>   Tue 2015/04/14 11:03:21 gammu-smsd[2816]: 42000:1:1064:[MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.6.20]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Signal) VALUES ("354232040876139", "", "yes", "yes", {fn CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()}, {

When I start the gammu's service, it start for a while less than 1 second, than stopped again.

- I use Gammu 1.33
- MySQL Connector/ODBC 3.51.30 to connect to my MySQL Database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tells you in the log what to do:

> Using generic SQL for ODBC, this might fail. In such case please set SQL configuration option.

Set `SQL = mysql` in SMSD configuration. See http://wammu.eu/docs/manual/smsd/config.html#option-SQL for more details.